# Android is it good practice to use one object of google api client for different purposes like activityRecognization, location service and geofences?

Tags: android, geolocation, google-api-client, android-geofence

It is a good practice to use one object of `Google API client` for different purposes like `activityRecognization`, `location service` and `geofences` in Android  or we have to use one seperate object of GoogleApiClient for each one?

My main task is to save battery life and less resource utilization.

Comment: what do you mean by "use one object of Google API client"?

Comment: My meaning is to create one class  that provide google api client object and also responsible to connect/disconnect google api client object. and separate classes for location provider and geofence manager and activityRecognization api. and all these class will use one class that provider google api client object.